# how to give user an option of conditional Install of Desktop and Quick Launch Shortcuts?

Tags: .net-3.5, setup-project

i have created an installer(dot net deployment project) on VS 2005 which automatically installs my application's shortcut on desktop and quick launch.

Now i want to give user an option to choose whether he wants to have the shortcut on desktop/quicklauch or both.It may be in form of checkboxes or radio buttons.

Can you please tell me how can i proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a custom dialog with some checkboxes. Each checkbox installer property can then be used by a custom action which deletes the unselected shortcuts. Please note that in this case all shortcuts need to be created manually in your setup project.

Another solution is to create the shortcuts from a custom action, again based on the checkbox properties.

Comment: Thanks for replying, can u please refer me any article/blog where i can know how to create shortcuts manually in set up project. i havent created it before.Tanx.

Comment: In File System Editor right-click in a folder and select "Create New Shortcut" context menu item.